# Creating an ArrayList that combines fields from two objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I am new to Java and am using BlueJ.

Overview of the context of the program.

I am trying to create a Club Database (arraylist, not actual database) where the user can add a new climber (name, age, gender) and which mountain they've climbed (name, height) to the arraylist.

I've created the Climber class and the mountain class. I've also created an ArrayList for the climbers and can add to this array. My question is.. How can I add a climber to the climber ArrayList, and be able to add which mountain they've climbed and its height at the same time?

The method of adding a climber needs to access both the Climber and Mountain class? Do I need to pass the fields from the Mountain class into Climber?

Whilst code solving the issue is appreciated, would be helpful if I was shown in the right direction so I can understand it more!

Thanks.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class ClubStats here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class ClubStats
{
    // An ArrayList for storing climber details.
    private ArrayList<Climber> climbers;

    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class ClubStats
    */
    public ClubStats()
   {
       // Initialise instance variables.
       climbers = new ArrayList<Climber>();
    }

    public void addClimber(Climber newName)
    {
        climbers.add(newName);
    }

   public Climber getClimber(String name)
   {
       Climber foundClimber = null;
       int index = 0;
       boolean searching = true;

       while(searching && index < climbers.size()) {
           Climber climber = climbers.get(index);
           if(climber.getName().equals(name)) {
                   searching = false;
                   foundClimber = climber;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(name + " not found");
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return foundClimber;
        }

    public void displayList()
    {
        for (int item = 0; item<climbers.size();
        item++) {
            Climber climber = climbers.get(item);
            System.out.println(climber.getName() + (" ") + climber.getAge() + (" ") 
            + climber.getGender());
        }
    }
}


public class Climber
{
    // Instance variables.
    // The climber name.
    private String name;
    // The climber age
    private int age;
    // The climber gender.
    private String gender;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Climber
     */
    public Climber (String newName, int newAge, String newGender)
    {
        // Initialise instance variables.
        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
        gender = newGender;

    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for climber's name.
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the climber's name.
     */
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for climber's age.
     */
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;

    }

    /**
     * Set the climber's age.
     */
    public void setAge(int newAge)
    {
        age = newAge;

    }

     /**
     * Set the climer's gender.
     */
   public String getGender()
   {
       return gender;
   } 

   /**
     * Accessor method for climber's gender.
     */
    public void getGender(String newGender)
    {
        gender = newGender;

    }


}

public class Mountain
{
    // Instance variables.
    private double height;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Mountain
     */
    public Mountain(String mName, double mHeight)
    {
        // Initialise instance variables
        name = mName;
        height = mHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for mountain name.
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the mountain name.
     */
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for mountain height.
     */
    public double getHeight()
    {
        // put your code here
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * Set the mountain height.
     */
    public void setHeight(double newHeight)
    {
        height = newHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a multidimensional array that stores both Climbers and Mountains? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your intention, but I don't see why you are using an array list for something like this. Why not have a "mountain" field in the climber class that can keep track of the mountains climbed? It can even be an arrayList<Mountain> field in which case you can add all the mountains they've climbed to this list and have that bound to each Climber.

Answer (score 3):

A `Climber` can contain a `List<Mountain>` of the `Mountain`a that this `Climber` climbed.

You can add an `addMountain(Mountain mountain)` method to `Climber` class which would add a `Mountain` to that `List`.

You can add a getter method `List<Mountain> getMountainList()` that would return that `List`.

This way, for each `Climber` you have access to the `Mountain`s this `Climber` has climbed.

Note that if multiple `Climber`s have climbed the same `Mountain`, they can all contain a reference to that same `Mountain` instance in their `List<Mountain>` (i.e. no need to create a copy of that `Mountain` instance for each `Climber`).